# How can you create one file from many png files in terminal?

Tags: pdf, png

**Example of data**

```
06-7-1-B.png
06-7-2-B.png
07-3-1-B.png
07-3-2-B.png
06-6-1-P.png
06-6-2-P.png
07-12-1-P.png
07-12-2-P.png
07-6-1-P.png
07-6-2-P.png
07-7-1-P.png
07-7-2-P.png
08-2-1-P.png
08-2-2-P.png
08-2-3-P.png
08-7-1-P.png
08-7-2-P.png
08-7-3-P.png
08-7-4-P.png
08-9-1-P.png
08-9-2-P.png
```

I want to join the files together as follows.
For instance, the files 06-7-1-B.png and 06-7-2.png should be joined together and renamed as 06-7-B.png.

**How can you create one file either png or pdf from many png -files in terminal?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be clearer in what you mean by "joining" two images, it is not obvious. You could mean anything from creating a montage, i.e. "glueing" the images together side-by-side, to some kind of "composition" where the images are stacked on top of each other, perhaps using alpha-channel transparency to let lower layers shine through.

For many of these, you should look into [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) as a way of doing it from the command line.

Comment: @unwind: I mean to put one image at the bottom of another image such that the image with smallest sheet number for a given exercise is at the top.

Answer (score 2):

Try [ImageMagick http://www.imagemagick.org](http://www.imagemagick.org) (as suggested by unwind):

montage +frame +shadow +label -geometry +0+0 -tile 2x1 
        06-7-1-B.png 06-7-2.png 06-7-B.png

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the Netpbm tools. Netpbm is a collection of small quick tools meant to be used from the command line (or scripts). There are many tools, each with its own purpose, and they can be chained together with pipes to do complex operations. See the [documentation](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/).

There's also ImageMagick, but in most cases Netpbm will run more quickly and use less memory. If you have smallish images this won't be a concern.